# Div expanding on both sides vertically when width is unknown and using translate(-50%, -50%);

Tags: css, reactjs

https://codepen.io/codepen19871/pen/KKQZgwQ

Is there a way to fix this behavior? I want to make sure that the div expands downward and never upward when adding text. Because of this, I need to used fixed width, but if I use fixed width, I can't make the div responsive to the size of the content. Is there a way to fix this?

```
 .child {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
    min-width: 10%;
    max-width: 20%;
    top: 90px;
    left: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

If I remove translate, it won't center. I also tried using other styling such as:

```
width: max-content;
```

But nothing works, there doesn't seem to be a solution that doesn't require javascript. If so, is there a way to make it work in React and make it behave like as though I used max-content?

I just need to center the div without the div expanding above, it's as simple as that.

Comment: What do you mean by expanding above?

Answer (score 0):

You should use flexbox if you want to center your div, I'm not exactly sure what you're attempting to do, but here is my interpretation.

```css
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.child {
    align-self: start;
    max-width: 20%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The second div cannot be a child of the parent.

Comment: Why is that? and What's the point of naming your divs parent and child then?

Comment: See my update, what do you think?

Comment: It's not supposed to be inside the parent. I wouldn't use absolute positioning if I could put it inside the parent.

Comment: As you present things here there is no point to position the child absolutely and to put it outside the parent, could you give more detail as of what you're trying to achieve, this will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Move child div under parent div and set Top 50%

```css
 

 .parent{
     width: 100%;
     height: 200px;
     background-color: #8ae6a2;
     position: relative;
    }      
    .child {
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
     min-width: 10%;
     max-width: 20%;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     position:absolute;
     z-index: 2;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     overflow-wrap: break-word;
     }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
   234234234343434234324324343242342342343242343243423
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's going to stay in the middle and expand upward and downward at the same time when you add text to it instead of expanding downward only, and the second div cannot be a child of the parent.